# Why doesn't the RewriteCond prevent the RewriteRule from processing?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I've got the following in my .conf file used for cache busting js:

```
<Directory "/www/virtual/site/html/js/">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^\d+\/(.+)$ $1 [L]
</Directory>
```

The idea here is to rewrite site.com/js/123456/script.js to site.com/js/script.js

(The rewriting works just fine)

If I look at the rewrite log the part I'm not understanding is that it is applying the RewriteRule to the script after the interal redirect... Shouldn't the `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` prevent it from processing the RewriteRule since the file exists?

Rewrite Log

```
[rid#2b607f8f2dc8/initial] (3) [perdir /www/virtual/site2/html/js/] add path info postfix: /www/virtual/site2/html/js/1234 -> /www/virtual/site2/html/js/1234/script.js
[rid#2b607f8f2dc8/initial] (3) [perdir /www/virtual/site2/html/js/] strip per-dir prefix: /www/virtual/site2/html/js/1234/script.js -> 1234/script.js
[rid#2b607f8f2dc8/initial] (3) [perdir /www/virtual/site2/html/js/] applying pattern '^\d+\/(.+)$' to uri '1234/script.js'
[rid#2b607f8f2dc8/initial] (2) [perdir /www/virtual/site2/html/js/] rewrite '1234/script.js' -> 'script.js'
[rid#2b607f8f2dc8/initial] (3) [perdir /www/virtual/site2/html/js/] add per-dir prefix: script.js -> /www/virtual/site2/html/js/script.js
[rid#2b607f8f2dc8/initial] (2) [perdir /www/virtual/site2/html/js/] strip document_root prefix: /www/virtual/site2/html/js/script.js -> /js/script.js
[rid#2b607f8f2dc8/initial] (1) [perdir /www/virtual/site2/html/js/] internal redirect with /js/script.js [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rid#2b6073eb14a8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /www/virtual/site2/html/js/] strip per-dir prefix: /www/virtual/site2/html/js/script.js -> script.js
[rid#2b6073eb14a8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir /www/virtual/site2/html/js/] applying pattern '^\d+\/(.+)$' to uri 'script.js'
[rid#2b6073eb14a8/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir /www/virtual/site2/html/js/] pass through /www/virtual/site2/html/js/script.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mod_rewrite (by design) keeps on applying rewrite-rules, till the url no longer changes.

So the first time it rewrite `1234/script.js` to `script.js` the second time it tries to apply the rule, the pattern regular expression doesn't match and `script.js` is 'passed through'.

This is the way it is supposed to work. It can sometimes be a pain, but it makes mod_rewrite a lot more powerful/useful.

**edit**

mod_rewite first tests the `RewriteRule` pattern, before trying to apply the `RewriteCond`'s. This is so you can use backreferences $0, $1 etc. in your RewriteCond. After all the RewriteCond's it will create the substitution string, so it can also use backrefereces %0, %1. etc. See also the diagram below.

So this is why it tried to apply the pattern before testing if the file exists.

[image: apache mod_rewrite flow]

Comment: I get that it applies the rules again... What I don't get is why it tries to apply the pattern when it does not match the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f. My assumption would be that it should not even try and apply the pattern because of the RewriteCond